# .NET Web Service Which References a Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, web-config, class-library

I have a class library from a previous developer (`c# .NET 3.5`) with some methods inside and I aim to use these within a *.NET web service (WCF)* to be consumed via an ESB process.

Inside the class library, some of the methods connect to a database to collect data. Currently the DB conn strings are embedded within the methods themselves.

I'd of course like to place these within a web config file if possible along side the WS.

Is it possible for a class lib (`DLL`) to be referenced within a `WCF` (even ASMX) web service and the methods within the class be able to see a conn string in a web config? Or is tehre no way they can pickup the web config file as its effectively a seperate library we are using (that could be used in winforms, webforms etc.)?

Or should I look to get the methods in the class changed, and not have the DB sections in there, I could switch things up and have the DB work done outside the class lib (inside my web service directly) meaning I can easily utilise the web config to host DB connections?

Thoughts ?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the class library and the DB conn strings that are embedded within the methods, how do they retrieve the connection details within those methods? From an internal connection string or hardcoded?

Comment: If the connection strings are hard coded then this is bad and you should change them if you can.  Have the classes take the connection string as a parameter in their constructor or in the methods if they are static.

Comment: The conn strings are embedded within the methods. But I can change that. I just wondered whether its better to a) try to get the class methods to use a web.config file (if ones there) or b) as you mention remove the hardcoded conns and pass them in as params from my methods directly within my web service?

Comment: I would recommend @Ben Robinsons recommendation with your Option b as it then creates a single point of connectionstring definition (inside your webservice) and re-usability for future implementations, meaning they don't have to remember to set a web.config's settings for it to connect properly

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for your advice Bernd/Ben, I'll proceed with option B.